# Azure B2C Custom Flow Add field to login

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure B2C Custom Flow where I have defined the TrustFrameworkExtension.xml and signupsignin.xml.  I have added the technicalProfile listed below with the expectation that a new free form text field will be added to the log in screen where the user can add their customer service rep's name.  Unfortunately, this field is not added the login screen, but since I have the default value set to "Joe Representative", every login has an api call that is passing in "Joe Representative".  So I have the part about passing the value to my API completed, I just need to know what I need to do to get the free form text to be displayed on the UI.  Suggestions?

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>            
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://somewickedcoolurl</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
            <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="repName" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="repName" DefaultValue="Joe Representative" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an orchestration step with `Type=CombinedSignInAndSignUp` and also modify the Sign In page elements. This step type will always default to username/password regardless of adding output claims to the selfAsserted technical profile that controls the Sign In function.

Comment: MSFT, thanks for the information. Is there guidance on how to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @VegasJ. You should add another orchestration step, after the login one, that refers to a self-asserted technical profile that prompts for the "repName" claim.